# SharePoint 2019 ON PREMISE - Cant order news items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem, newsfeed

I have an ON PREMISE installation with a modern experience Communication Site as the root. I am unable to sort news items. When I go to the **Manage Posts** location and make any change it is not reflected in the news webpart which is sitting on the root communication page.

Is there a way to sort these items in the order I would choose - not order by date or author. They need to be sorted by relevance to our communication.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2019, there's no sort function in news web part. As a workaround, I would suggest you use higtlighted web part instead. You could choose news type to be displayed in the web part and sort the news. Like the below screenshot:

[image]

Note: Both news web part and highlighted content web part are based on the search. If the news are not crawled by Search Service Application, they cannot be displayed in the web part. So when you make some changes, it will not be reflected in the web part immediately. After the changes are crawled, then it would be reflected in your web part

Comment: Thanks Michael - it looks as though I will have to create a managed property to handle this. I am not sure how do this. I did attempt and it has not worked.